# Accessing parent attribute from inside child window

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt5

My main window has a variable self.x setup in the INIT. Then I need to access this value from the popup password box that is created. This is just a test script to get my point accross. I'm assuming it's something with the inheritance stuff, all that is still a little foreign to me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

# Created by MyWindow
class LoginDlg(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginDlg, self).__init__()

        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        # THIS IS THE LINE I NEED IT TO PULL X FROM PARENT
        self.password.setText(self.x)
        self.button_box = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        self.button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        layout.setFieldGrowthPolicy(QtWidgets.QFormLayout.AllNonFixedFieldsGrow)
        layout.addRow('Password', self.password)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_box)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Login")
        self.setMinimumWidth(350)

# Main parent window
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        
        self.edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Get input from dialog")
        button.clicked.connect(self.get_login)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.x = "PASS THIS STRING"

    def get_login(self):
        login = LoginDlg()
        if login.exec_():
            self.edit.setText(login.password.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Normally I would just pass this data through the constructor, but let's say I have a lot of data that I don't want to pass back and forth, is there a way to access parent attributes another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get too complicated and just pass the value of that variable through the constructor:

```
class LoginDlg(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super(LoginDlg, self).__init__()

        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.password.setText(x)
        # ...
```

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    # ...

    def get_login(self):
        login = LoginDlg(self.x)
        if login.exec_():
            self.edit.setText(login.password.text())
```

Another similar option is to access "password" in get_login:

```
class LoginDlg(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginDlg, self).__init__()

        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        # self.password.setText(self.x)
        self.button_box = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel
        )
        # ...
```

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    # ...

    def get_login(self):
        login = LoginDlg()
        login.password.setText(self.x)
        if login.exec_():
            self.edit.setText(login.password.text())
```

**Note:** my answer does not try to implement what the OP asks is to "access a class from another" (there is no relationship so using parent-child is incorrect) since that complicates the modularization because if a object could affect the other, in general. I think the OP has an XY problem as it asks how to implement a possible solution instead of the underlying problem which is "how to share information between classes"

Comment: Was just about to edit my question, I have a lot of data I need to pass back and forth, is there a way to do this without the constructor?

Comment: @user2797519 My second option I think covers your modification

Comment: @user2797519 On the other hand, I do not understand what relationship exists between having a lot of data with the constructor, anyway you will have to assign the information through the constructor, directly to the widgets or through another method that does the above. IMO you are getting too complicated for such a simple and trivial